# Know what methods are in .jar files

Tags: java, jar, imagej, medical

I know that there is a plugin for ImageJ that handles NIfTI-1 files (http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/nifti.html).

But all its instructions on that page is to use ImageJ as a standalone program, however I am using its API. How can I know **what methods are available in this jar file without its source**?

I couldn't find the source code either.

For the supported archives in imageJ (such as DICOM) is quite easy :

```
public class ImageJTest {
    public static void main(){
                        String path = "res/vaca.dcm"; 
            FileInputStream fis;
            ImageView image;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(path);
                DICOM d = new DICOM(fis);
                d.run(path);
                // Stretches the histogram because the pictures were being
                // displayed too dark.
                (new ij.plugin.ContrastEnhancer()).stretchHistogram(d, 0.1);
                Image picture = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(d.getBufferedImage(),
                        null);
                // Makes the size standard for thumbnails
                image = new ImageView(picture);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

How can I load the NIfTI-1 files in imageJ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the class files, which are embedded in the jar file (as @Alvin Thompson pointed out, these are just zip files by a different name), you can use the reflection API to mine the class files to get their methods. A sample follows for one class, cribbed from [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html):

```
Method[] methods = thisClass.getClass().getMethods(); // thisClass is an instance of the class you're working with

for(Method method : methods){
    System.out.println("method = " + method.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JAR files are just fancy ZIP files. You can rename the file to `foo.zip`, then use any unzip utility to expand its contents. You should be able to at least see what the class files are, and the javadocs may be bundled with it (unlikely these days but possible).

However, if you just want to know what methods are available, probably the best way is to add the JAR to the class path of a project in NetBeans, Eclipse, or IntelliJ and use their code completion features to figure out the API methods and classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can do even a decompile of the jar and see the code that is behind each class using a decompiler. 
A good one i found: Java Decompiler 
JD-GUI home page: http://java.decompiler.free.fr

It does really good it's job. At least in the tasks i had.

Comment: Erreur 403 - Refus de traitement de la requête (Interdit - Forbidden)

Comment: You also can get it from here.
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/JD-GUI.shtml